# Drag Dropping from WPF to Notepad

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop

I did some research and found this :

```
DataObject d = new DataObject();
d.SetData(DataFormats.Serializable, myObject);
d.SetData(DataFormats.Text, myObject.ToString());
myForm.DoDragDrop(d, DragDropEffects.Copy);
```

code snippet to drag drop in win forms.

And i tried implementing it like this (**WPF**) :

```
private void listView1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                DataObject d = new DataObject();
                d.SetData(DataFormats.Serializable, listView1.SelectedItem);
                d.SetData(DataFormats.Text, listView1.SelectedItem.ToString());
                DragDrop.DoDragDrop(listView1, d, DragDropEffects.Copy);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Now I had thought when i drag dropped the ListViewItem into notepad it would probably copy the class name of the selected item (Because that's what listView1.SelectedItem.ToString()) is... But instead Notepad showed a picture of a cancel symbol while hovering, and copied nothing when i let go of the mouse button.

The over all goal of this is to change the class into a comma delimited string so when it copy pastes into notepad all of the data of the class will be in a nice format.

But if someone could help me just get the class name to copy i'm sure i could figure it out from there :o

Comment: I'd try dropping the first setdata call.

Comment: Yea i guess that's a bit redundant haha, still doesn't work tho

Comment: Are you sure notepad allows dropping of text items? I see that I can drop a file into notepad and that it'll open it and read it in, but I can't seem to be able to drop text.

Comment: Oh.... What the hell? It allows entire FILE dropping, but not text dropping?

Comment: There's probably a way to convert the list view item i have selected to a text file to drop it then ?

Comment: Well, if it really wants a file, just make one and D&D that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So.... Yea.

```
  bool alreadycopying = false;

    private void listView1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Released)
            {
                alreadycopying = false;
            }


            if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed && alreadycopying == false)
            {
                alreadycopying = true;
                System.IO.StreamWriter test = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\SuperSecretTestFile.txt");
                test.WriteLine("Test");
                test.Close();

                List<String> testlist = new List<string>();
                testlist.Add(@"C:\SuperSecretTestFile.txt");

                DataObject d = new DataObject();
                d.SetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, testlist.ToArray<string>());
                DragDrop.DoDragDrop(listView1, d, DragDropEffects.All);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

After much bashing of poor notepad technology, c# comes out victorious <.<